# toFixed() not working well with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tofixed

Why am I not able to use `toFixed(2)` when doing a console.log of the prices array below? Why is `toFixed` not working in this instance?

I get the following error: `Error: VM1105:8 Uncaught TypeError: prices.toFixed is not a function at <anonymous>:8:20`

Here's the simple code:

```
var prices = [1.23, 48.11, 90.11, 8.50, 9.99, 1.00, 1.10, 67.00];

// your code goes here
prices[0]= 1.99;
prices[2]= 99.99;
prices[6]= 1.95;

console.log(prices.toFixed(2));
```

When I just print out console.log(prices);
I get the following, which is missing the decimals in the actual array. Why is this and how to remedy it?

```
(8) [1.99, 48.11, 99.99, 8.5, 9.99, 1, 1.95, 67]
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: toFixed is a method of Number Object, not an Array.

Comment: @brk perhaps you could help make it clearer. There's three questions, each followed by question marks. What did you miss?

Comment: @Kusuma but aren't these number objects stored in an array?

Comment: @AgentZebra Yes.. You can apply .toFixed method on Number Objects. Not on Array.

Comment: @Kusuma that's whats confusing me. These are number objects in an array, so they're still number objects.  Or, does a number object stop being a number object when it's in an array, and becomes an array object? confusing, why would that be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is a method of `Number`, not of `Array`. You need to map all values and apply `toFixed` on it.

```js
var prices = [1.23, 48.11, 90.11, 8.50, 9.99, 1.00, 1.10, 67.00];

prices[0]= 1.99;
prices[2]= 99.99;
prices[6]= 1.95;

console.log(prices.map(v => v.toFixed(2)));
```

Comment: nice , but give a notice to others about browser support when u use Arrow functions ... dos not work in **ALL IE** versions , **ALL Blackberry** and **ALL Opera Mini for mobiles** also **android < 4.4** , and especially **safari** does not support it completely yet see [MDN Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) also : [browsers support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions), using normal function is better to support all your clients : `prices = prices.map(function(v){ return v.toFixed(2)});`

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you. I think where I am getting confused is that to my mind I think these are number objects stored in an array, so I'm confused by the need to map them. Though to other people I think this seems entirely logical. So, if a number object is stored in an array, it's not a number object any more but an array object? That seems overly complicated, what would be the reason for designing JS this?

Comment: please add what you mean by *number object* to the question.